# MONACAアプリバックグラウンドでもBGMが鳴り続ける

Tags: monaca

PhoneGap の Media APIを使用してmp3をBGMとして再生しているのですが、
androidのホームボタンを押して、ホーム画面へ表示が切り替わってもBGMが鳴り続けます。
どうすればいいですか？

Answer (score 1):

ホームボタンを押すと`pause`イベントが発火しますので、そのイベントハンドラ内で停止すると良いと思います。

```
document.addEventListener("pause", function(){
    media.pause();
}, false);
```

参考: イベント - Monacaドキュメント - Monaca Docs
http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/reference/phonegap_34/ja/events/events/#pause-ja

Comment: できました。
アプリをバックグラウンドでも実行するがOFFになっていたのが原因でした。